# How to use array objects based on condition using React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using react functional components inside that, I have two different array objects. I would like to render the array objects based on the condition which I have. I'm using the function hooks to define a reference and assign to it dynamically. But, this is returning null. can someone help me on this ? In the below code `isDemandGraph` is returning `null` while rendering.

```
     function gridHeatMap(props) {
          const heatMap = [
            { color: 'redVeryHigh', value: 50 },
            { color: 'redHigh', value: 25 },
            { color: 'redMedium', value: 20 },
            { color: 'redLow', value: 15 },
            { color: 'white', value: 0 },
            { color: 'greenLow', value: 15 },
            { color: 'greenMedium', value: 20 },
            { color: 'greenHigh', value: 25 },
            { color: 'greenVeryHigh', value: 50 },
          ];
        
          const demandHeatMap = heatMap.reverse();
        
          const isDemandGraph = useRef(null);
        
          const { height, title, viewName } = props;
          const classes = useStyles();
        
          return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
              <div className={classes.title}>{title}</div>
              <Grid container spacing={0}>
                {viewName === 'demand' ? { isDemandGraph: heatMap } : { isDemandGraph: demandHeatMap }}
                {isDemandGraph.map((item, index) => {
                  return (
                    <Grid item style={{ flexGrow: '1', height, width: '11%' }} className={item.color}>
                    </Grid>
               </Grid>
            </div>
)
```

Comment: You initialize it to `null` and never touch it again, it's unclear what you're expecting.

Comment: @DaveNewton: `{viewName === 'demand' ? { isDemandGraph: heatMap } : { isDemandGraph: demandHeatMap }}`. In this statement. I'm updating the const value with the array which I need based on condition.And using that to populate on Grid in very next statement `{isDemandGraph.map((item, index) => {`

Comment: @TechGeek is not the right way to update. You are returning newly created objects. And not updating `isDemandGraph` value. Also why to create a ref?

Comment: @Medi: Is there any alternative way to update that variable ?

Comment: @TechGeek Nothing is being updated--it's a no-op ternary expression. [The `useRef` docs may be helpful.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Comment: @TechGeek, are you using `isDemandGraph` else where?

Comment: Why are you using ref for an array of objects instead of state?

Comment: You can make `isDemandGraph` a local state variable and update it with a `useEffect()` hooks triggered by `viewName`

Comment: @Medi: Yes!! `{viewName === 'demand' ? { isDemandGraph: heatMap } : { isDemandGraph: demandHeatMap }}` after this, I'm using that in very next statement `{isDemandGraph.map((item, index) => {`.

Comment: You don't have an error in your code ? I see only the opening tag of the grid with the container attr.

Comment: `[...viewName === 'demand'? heatMap :  heatMap.reverse()].map`. Maybe this is enough.

Comment: @ValeriF21 It's closed by the `</Grid>` that appears at the same indentation level--except that the `return` of the `map` appears unterminated. :shrug:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work that way, calling the `isDemandGraph` inside the ternary operator does not assign value to the same.
Also, you should use `useState` instead of `useRef` for your usecase.
I am adding the updated code snippet, it should work as expected:

```js
 function gridHeatMap(props) {
          const heatMap = [
            { color: 'redVeryHigh', value: 50 },
            { color: 'redHigh', value: 25 },
            { color: 'redMedium', value: 20 },
            { color: 'redLow', value: 15 },
            { color: 'white', value: 0 },
            { color: 'greenLow', value: 15 },
            { color: 'greenMedium', value: 20 },
            { color: 'greenHigh', value: 25 },
            { color: 'greenVeryHigh', value: 50 },
          ];
        
          const demandHeatMap = heatMap.reverse();
        
          const { height, title, viewName } = props;
          const [isDemandGraph, setIsDemandGraph ] = useState(viewName === 'demand' ? heatMap : demandHeatMap);
          // setIsDemandGraph can be used to update the value of `isDemandGraph`
          
          const classes = useStyles();
        
          return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
              <div className={classes.title}>{title}</div>
              <Grid container spacing={0}>
                {isDemandGraph.map((item, index) => {
                  return (
                    <Grid item style={{ flexGrow: '1', height, width: '11%' }} className={item.color}>
                    </Grid>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `useState` instead of `useRef` and use `useEffect` to listen prop changes like:

```
function gridHeatMap(props) {
          const { height, title, viewName } = props;
          const [isDemandGraph, setisDemandGraph] = useState([]);
          const classes = useStyles();

          const heatMap = [
            { color: 'redVeryHigh', value: 50 },
            { color: 'redHigh', value: 25 },
            { color: 'redMedium', value: 20 },
            { color: 'redLow', value: 15 },
            { color: 'white', value: 0 },
            { color: 'greenLow', value: 15 },
            { color: 'greenMedium', value: 20 },
            { color: 'greenHigh', value: 25 },
            { color: 'greenVeryHigh', value: 50 },
          ];
        
          const demandHeatMap = heatMap.reverse();
        
          useEffect(() => {
             viewName === 'demand' ?  setisDemandGraph(heatMap) : setisDemandGraph(demandHeatMap);
          }, [viewName]);
        
          return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
              <div className={classes.title}>{title}</div>
              <Grid container spacing={0}>
                {isDemandGraph.map((item, index) => {
                  return (
                    <Grid item style={{ flexGrow: '1', height, width: '11%' }} className={item.color}>
                    </Grid>
            </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is how I would go (please notice I modified a bit the returned JSX, as the one in your code did not look correct to me, so you might want to double check it):

```js
import React, { useState, useMemo, useEffect } from 'react';
// ... other imports

function gridHeatMap({ height, title, viewName }) {
  const heatMap = useMemo(() => ([
    { color: 'redVeryHigh', value: 50 },
    { color: 'redHigh', value: 25 },
    { color: 'redMedium', value: 20 },
    { color: 'redLow', value: 15 },
    { color: 'white', value: 0 },
    { color: 'greenLow', value: 15 },
    { color: 'greenMedium', value: 20 },
    { color: 'greenHigh', value: 25 },
    { color: 'greenVeryHigh', value: 50 },
  ]), []);
  
  const [currentHeatMap, setCurrentHeatMap] = useState(heatMap);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    viewName === 'demand'
      ? setCurrentHeatMap(heatMap)
      : setCurrentHeatMap(heatMap.reverse());
  }, [viewName]);
  
  const classes = useStyles();
  
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <div className={classes.title}>{title}</div>
      
      <GridContainer spacing={0}>
        {
          currentHeatMap.map((item, index) => (
            <Grid
              key={`grid-${index}-${item.color}`}
              className={item.color}
              style={{ flexGrow: '1', height, width: '11%' }}
              item
            />
          ));
        }
      </GridContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default gridHeatMap;
```